# Scala: Spark: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try make Apache Spark job on scala. I'm novice in Scala and and earlier use Pyspark.
Have error when the job starts.
Code:

```
object SparkRMSP_full {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("parse_full_rmsp_job")
      .getOrCreate()

    val raw_data_df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "10.1.24.111:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "dev.etl.fns.rmsp.raw-data")
      .load()

    println(raw_data_df.isStreaming)
    raw_data_df.printSchema
  }
}
```

spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11:2.1.0 --master local --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 2g --driver-memory 1g --executor-cores 2 "C:\tools\jar\streaming_spark.jar"
```

And I have error:

```
20/07/15 15:05:32 WARN SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load SparkRMSP_full.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SparkRMSP_full
```

How I must declare the class correctly?

**UPD:**

build.sbt:

```
name := "streaming_spark"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly" % "2.3.1"
```

project sctructure  on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Tqcp1ZGm)

Comment: how did you create a jar file, maven or sbt can you share it? Also add `--class SparkRMSP_full`

Comment: I'm build jar file with sbt in IDEA. And I add `--class` into spark-submit, but same error

Comment: can you add the sbt content and folder structure?

Comment: Is complete. Catalogs on pasterbin

Comment: Can you paste the path of `SparkRMSP_full` object ?

Comment: src\main\scala\MainApp.scala

Answer (score 1):

Change your spark-submit command like below & try again.

```
spark-submit \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11:2.1.0 \
  --master local \
  --num-executors 2 \
  --executor-memory 2g \
  --driver-memory 1g \
  --executor-cores 2 \
  --class SparkRMSP_full \  # you might need add your fully qualified package name with class name
  "C:\tools\jar\streaming_spark.jar"
```

Comment: which build tool are you using maven or sbt .. can you post that code in question ??

Comment: what I must post? I novice in Java-like codding. I run "Build" in IDEA and make jar.

Comment: pom.xml or build.sbt file ? and how are you builiding jar file ?

Comment: I'm build jar file with sbt in IDEA. build.sbt in question

Comment: try building fat jar file using sbt also include main class.